# Texture loose its details after rendering on quad

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, shader

This is how my texture looks by default:

[image]

But after I try to render it on quad, it looks like this:

[image]

I tried different import settings and different compression types and still no luck. [Here's my current import settings.](http://take.ms/EKAjd)

Shader that I use to render this texture: [Link](http://pastebin.com/PJnUMahs) I assume the problem may lay here, but I don't see any code that may cause the problem.

Does anyone know what I supposed to do to save all the details?

Comment: have you tried to increase its max size ?

Comment: @UriPopov texture's default size is 12x80px, MaxSize value is set to 128. I think trying bigger numbers will make no difference.

Comment: Is there any way in which you can share a small project which demonstrates the issue? It doesn't have to be your full project. And you're sure the quad is above the other mesh (not exactly on it) and doesn't intersect?

Comment: I was just being stupid and forgot about "Cutout" parameter in Transparent Cutout shader. Lowering default value of this parameter solved the problem and now it doesn't cut any small details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely it was my bad. I just had to lower the value of `Cutout` parameter of my Transparent Cutout shader from `0.5` to `0.25`